# Creating but not saving NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So I have created a sub-class of NSManagedObject, and now I want to create a temporary clone of an instance, but don't want to save the clone.  How do I do this?

Here is a rough example, where Person is a sub-class of NSManagedObject.

```
Person *billy = [Person initWithStuff:stuff];
```

We initialize billy, and save billy to a context.

```
Person *bobby = billy;
bobby.name = @"Bobby";
```

We create bobby, and modify one attribute.

But now I do not want the modifications to bobby to save to billy, and I do not want to save bobby to the context.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't reference billy to bobby like that.  You are not making a clone you are just creating another pointer to the same object in memory.

If you want to create a **new** `Person` entity then you need to create it with the proper initializer and then copy the attributes from billy to bobby.  From there you can use the new bobby `Person`.  Saving it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a copy of the object. What you did is create an second pointer, which points to the same object.
The second thing you want to do is to create an NSManagedObject without a context.

To copy a object normally you would implement the NSCopying protocol with the method copyWithZone, but this is not possible cause NSManagedObject do not use the normal constructor.

What you can do is implement your own copy method.

**Person.m**

```
- (id)copy {
    // Create object
    Person *copiedPerson = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:nil];

    // Now copy all properties
    copiedPerson.name = self.name;

    // return object
    return copiedPerson;
}
```

**Now you can us it like this.**

```
Person *billy = [Person initWithStuff:stuff];
Person *bobby = [billy copy];
bobby.name = @"Bobby";
```

Comment: I'm interested to know why you create the `copiedPerson` but not in an `NSManagedObjectContext`. Doesn't it need that to exist?

Comment: Normally you call context.save at any point and than all entities will be stored, but in the question he mentioned, that he do not want to store the copy, for this i passed nil as parameter, which will prohibit the call of context.addEntity, which is done internally